# Jquery Validation messages not clearing on msdropdown change

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, msdropdown

I have a form with two select boxes. First one is styled using msdropdown. I am validating the form using jquery validation(required).  When I submit the form that two select boxes will be validate and error messages is showing. Thats fine.

But my issue is when I just changed the select box options, the validation message is clearing for normal select box. But it is not clearing for msdropdown select box. I need to click again the submit button to clear the messages. What should I do to validate that when I changed the select box option?

This is my validation rules block.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {     
    $("body #webmenu").msDropDown();
    $("#frmTest").validate({
        rules: {
            normal: {
                required: true
            },
            webmenu: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have created a fiddle with the scenario. Please have a look at it.

http://jsfiddle.net/LHF3G/

Comment: you can remove the error manually

Comment: [tag:jquery-validation-engine] has nothing to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Edited tags.

Comment: @Manish, or he can trigger `.valid()` on the `mouseup` event.

Comment: @Sparky by manually i meant on change remove error http://jsfiddle.net/LHF3G/2/

Comment: @Manish, I understood what you meant... however, I think it's much better to let the plugin handle the error messages: http://jsfiddle.net/LHF3G/1/

Comment: @sparky didnt read the docum'n.:) valid method is better +1

Answer (score 2):

Use [the plugin's `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) to trigger a validation test on the element upon the `mouseup` event.  I used the browser's DOM inspector to find the target... the `<li>` with class `_msddli_`.

```
$('._msddli_').on('mouseup', function() { // target the custom line item on mouseup
    $('#webmenu').valid(); // validation test triggered on target element
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/LHF3G/1/**

---

**EDIT**:

Another version working the same as above:

```
$('#webmenu').on('change', function() {  // target the original select on change
    $(this).valid();  // validation test triggered on target element 
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/LHF3G/3/**

You can tweak the jQuery selectors and JavaScript event to suit any possible situation.  However, **the most important aspect here is that the `.valid()` method is the mechanism for  triggering the validation test, which in turn will toggle the error message as required.**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your support. I finally solved the issue by adding the following code.

```
 $('#webmenu').on('change', function(){ 
     $('#frmTest').valid(); 
 })
```

Comment: This is basically my answer.  Although, if you use `$(this).valid()`, you will trigger the validation test on the relevant element instead of the whole form.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/LHF3G/3/